# How to build an executable in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, exe

I am trying to create a standalone executable using VSC. In the projectName.csproj file, the output type is set to Exe, but whenever i try and build it creates a .DLL file. Can anyone tell me how i would go about creating an exe?

I cannot just use Visual Studio as the organization i work for makes more than the $100k minimum a year.

Comment: Update your csproj to set your runtime identifier as Windows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog

Comment: Visual Studio Community is free and should give you the required project types to get started with,. Alternatively you can try to use the dotnet cli commands to start a new project - [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore21)

Comment: See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/10/11/net-core-how-to-publish-a-self-contained-application-exe/

Comment: Default executables will be introduced in .net core 3.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#default-executables. For now you need to do what @PaulF mentioned.

Comment: did you check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#buildoptions

Comment: _"I cannot just use Visual Studio as the organization i work for makes more than the $100k minimum a year."_ - surely if the organisation you work for makes that amount of money it can afford to get you the right tool to do the job it wants you to do. If using the "free" option means you are taking extra time to do the job there is a good justification right there.

Comment: @Kirill _"...Visual Studio Community is `free`..."_ - **incorrect** for the context here which is for **organizations** .  [VS Community License](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt553321/).  I'm assuming you are not making say _device drivers_

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I am only a student assistant working 5 hour a week, on a minor project where i make some minor programs to help their workflow. But the organization don't qualify for the free version of Visual Studio, and since i am only here ones a week, they wont pay for one of the other versions.

Comment: @MickyD: looking in more detail at the license - if the organisation does not qualify as an enterprise (ie less than 250PC users AND less than $1million revenue) then up to 5 users can use the Community edition.